# Angular 5 URL of named router outlets

Tags: javascript, url, angular5, router-outlet

Is there a way to change the url that the named router outlet displays, for example:

http://.../me/(me:personal)

to

http://.../me/personal

but the functionality to stay the same?

Comment: I am also Facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
 this.router.navigate([{
  outlets: { outletname: ['path'] }
}],
  {
    skipLocationChange: true,
  }
)
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.