# Angular 6: outlet name showing on url how to remove it?

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, router-outlet

**router-outlet name showing on url.**
How to remove this I found the same question on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49831531/angular-5-url-of-named-router-outlets) is the link but there no answer was given. so I posted this again. In my project
URL showing like : http://localhost:4200/dashboard/(dashboardSection:profile)

but I want to make it like:

http://localhost:4200/dashboard/profile

http://localhost:4200/dashboard/list

I have provided all the code for routing.

**app.module.ts**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  { path: 'sign-up', component: SignUpComponent, canActivate: [PreventLoggedInAccess]  },
  { path: 'file', component: FileUploadComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], 
    children:[
    {
        path: "list",
        component: ListingListComponent,
        outlet: 'dashboardSection'
      },
      {
        path: "profile",
        component: ProfileEditComponent,
        outlet: 'dashboardSection'
      }
    ]
  },
  { path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

on Import section @NgModule({});

```
RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      { enableTracing: false } // <-- debugging purposes only
    ),
```

**dashboard.component.html**

```
<li [routerLink]="['/dashboard',{ outlets: { dashboardSection: ['list'] }}]"  routerLinkActive="active">List</li>
              <li [routerLink]="['/dashboard',{ outlets: { dashboardSection: ['profile'] } }]" routerLinkActive="active">profile</li>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular <router-outlet name="popup"> change URL path structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49515140/angular-router-outlet-name-popup-change-url-path-structure)

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for the answer I saw this post but there was the answer for clean URL not remove the outlet-name from URL

Comment: That's because there isn't one. That's how the routing works.